# How to proxy pass a fastapi backend and a react front end with custom endpoints using nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, proxy, fastapi

Have a react UI delivered on localhost:5000

Have a fastapi backend on localhost:8000

Both currently show up fine on their respective ports with the caveat that the api requires a trailing endpoint, i.e. `localhost:8000/docs` to get to the documentation.

Desire: when the user browses to `localhost` that the UI would show up, when they browse to `localhost/api` the docs page shows up, and when they browse to `localhost/api/endpoint` the api endpoint shows up (`localhost:8000/endpoint`) ... I have 2 out of 3, but cant figure out why the `/api` redirect to `8000/docs` is not happy.

I'm guessing I need to "rewrite" the location similarly to how it is re-written for the `/api/` but couldn't find a solution...

Interestingly even though `api/endpoint` works, `api/docs` does not, even though they should be "proxied" to the same location...

Additionally, it would also be preferred to not required the intermediate `/api` to get access to the endpoints so that `localhost/endpoint` would redirect to `localhost:8000/endpoint` directly.

nginx.conf:

```
events{
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/docs;
        }

        location /api/ {
            rewrite  ^/api/(.*)$  /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

related side question(s)... is there a way to see the routing that is actually performed? i.e. is there a way to actually see what address was passed back to the user... or if there is a way to instead of re-direct/proxy actually put the proxied address in the browser for quick debugging. Even if it is in a form of debugging i.e. `echo-nginx-module`

Comment: I see that the `return` command is useful, in that I could "return" the actual site instead of a `proxy_pass`... however I do not know which IP address they might have used to access this site (internal with some re-directs through other services such as wireguard)

Comment: Any reason to not just move the docs to `/` by setting it inside your FastAPI application? `app = FastAPI(docs_url="/")` (or `/api` if you want your FastAPI application to see the whole URL)

Comment: because I'm not in charge of the backend 8-) could probably do that, but I'd still like to learn what I am doing wrong so I can understand the syntax better.